# avoid form field while submit 3

Tags: php

I built a form with fields that have the same names as the db fields names.

I have code that when I submit the form I import the data to the DB without writing the specific names of the fields:

```
foreach ($_POST AS $field => $value)
    $sql[] = $field." = '". $value."'";

$sql = implode(' , ',$sql);

$query = "UPDATE clients SET ".$sql." WHERE (id = ".$clientID.") " ;
```

the problem is that I have some fields that I don't want to import to the db (because they don't even exist in the db).
Do you have any idea how to avoid those fields?

Thanks

Comment: `show columns from %table%`. If column exists  - add to query, it's simple

Comment: I really urge you to inform yourself about SQL injection and sanitization of user inputs. Please remember that all nowadays browsers include html code inspection and that even a input name can be forged to attack your database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try putting the elements that you do want into an array and ignoring the ones you don't want:

```
$post1 = $_POST[1]; // Elements that you do not want in sql statement
$post2 = $_POST[2];

// Elements you want in the db
$array = ($field3 => $_POST[3], $field4 => $_POST[4], $field5 => $_POST[5]);

foreach ($array AS $field => $value){
    $value = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $value); // Escape your strings and use mysqli (since mysql is deprecated)

    $sql[] = $field." = '". $value."'";
    $sql = implode(' , ',$sql);

    $query = "UPDATE clients SET ".$sql." WHERE (id = ".$clientID.") " ;
}
```

I tried not to change too much. From what it seems, your code is fine except for escaping your data and the need to separate fields.

Answer (score 0):

Your code as it stands would open you up to all sorts of SQL injection attacks. I would suggest that you don't access the $_POST superglobal directly.

You could have anything coming in via the $_POST variable being added to your SQL statement.

You should always consider how you filter and sanitise all the data coming from unknown sources.

To answer your question, as part of your filtering you could also have a list of form fields that you don't want to import to the db.

Answer (score 0):

An easy solution could be to add a prefix to the field names you don't want to be used in your query.

For example

```
<input type="email" name="*email">

foreach ($_POST AS $field => $value)
if(substr($field,0,1)<>"*")
{

    $sql[] = $field." = '". $value."'";
}
```